# how to write this code in right way in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

```
   $("#wedding").click(function() {  
        $(".wedding, .wedding div").addClass("menuclick"); 
    $(".homecoming div, .ourstory div, .weddingcrew div").removeClass("menuclick"); 
    });  

$("#homecoming").click(function() {  
        $(".homecoming, .homecoming div").addClass("menuclick");
    $(".wedding div, .ourstory div, .weddingcrew div").removeClass("menuclick"); 

    });  

$("#ourstory").click(function() {  
        $(".ourstory, .ourstory div").addClass("menuclick");
        $(".wedding div, .homecoming div, .weddingcrew div").removeClass("menuclick"); 

    });  

$("#weddingcrew").click(function() {  
        $(".weddingcrew, .weddingcrew div").addClass("menuclick");
        $(".wedding div, .ourstory div, .homecoming div").removeClass("menuclick"); 

    });
```

i wrote this code for animate css animation.there's four items, and when i click one one item is animate and others will return. i need  to know how to simplify this code.

Comment: what is `menuclick` css class? show the css code too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without changing your html, you could do this:

```
$("#wedding, #homecoming, #ourstory, #weddingcrew").click(function() {
  // remove menuclick class from all elements that currently have it
  $(".menuclick").removeClass("menuclick");
  // now add menuclick just to elements associated with the clicked item
  $("." + this.id).find("div").andSelf().addClass("menuclick"); 
});
```

This depends on the fact that your element ids are exactly the same as the corresponding classes on the elements they're associated with.

If you could add a common class, say `class="menu"` to the `#wedding, #homecoming`, etc. items then you could simplify the initial selector to `$(".menu")`.

P.S. If you're using jQuery v1.8 or later use [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) instead of [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/).

Comment: How about `$('.menuclick').removeClass("menuclick")` to tighten it up? If it's not in use elsewhere...

Comment: Good plan @WesleyMurch - answer updated to use this. Obviously if `menuclick` was used for other unrelated elements that first line inside the function would have to be `$(".wedding, .homecoming, .ourstory, .weddingcrew").find("div").andSelf().removeClass("menuclick");`

Comment: `.this.id` selects what.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - When jQuery calls your event handler it sets `this` to the "current" element, i.e., the element that the event occurred on (in this case the clicked element). So you can bind a single handler to multiple elements and then tell which element was clicked by using `this`. And then `this.id` obviously gives that element's id.

Comment: ok i get the `this.id` part but not >> `"." +` in `"." + this.id`

Comment: Oh, the expression `"." + this.id` produces a string like `".wedding"`, which is a selector that will match elements with the class `"wedding"`.